How to host two separate websites with Github Pages?
I am currently hosting a website clydekertzer.com with Github pages. I am trying to host a separate website called numbertaxonomy.com.
However, when I am trying to do the same thing with numbertaxonomy.com it is giving me the following error. Moreover, the link numbertaxonomy.com doesn't link with the github pages and instead has the basic squarespace page.

s://i.sstatic.net/oQr6dZA4.png)
I bought both of these domains with GoogleDomains/Squarespace. I followed the tutorial here that allowed me to have a custom domain for clydekertzer.com.

Please let me know what other information I can provide to help troubleshoot this.
